# Create a dynamic buddupress tab

Tags: php, urls, buddypress

I am trying to create a dynamic buddypress tab linked to a dynamic url that looks like this `localhost/wordpress/slug/username`

this tab should appear to any user visiting another user's profile,, and when clicked it should redirect to the user visited and not the user visiting , I mean that the username at the end of my URL should be replaced by the username of the current profile visited

I am using the wp_redirect function to redirect the user to this url but the probleme is that i don't know how to write this url ?

I've tried to create a variable like so `$user = wp_get_current_user();` to includ it like so `wp_redirect( "http://localhost/wordpress/slug/$user->display_name" );` but the final result is `http://localhost/wordpress2/slug/` i'm not even sure i should call this function current user so please someone help me

keep in mind that i'm writing my code in the function.php file in my theme folder

thats the code i added

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();




add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'create_tab3', 303 );
function create_tab3() {
    global $bp;
    bp_core_new_nav_item(
        array(
            'name'                    => 'my name',
            'slug'                    => 'slug', 
            'position'                => 21, 
            'default_subnav_slug'     => 'mySlug', // We add this submenu item below 
            'screen_function'         => 'redirect_user_to_tab3',
        )
    );

}
function redirect_user_to_tab3(){
    global $bp;
    wp_redirect( "http://localhost/wordpress2/slug/$user->display_name" );
    exit;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an object variable, `$user->display_name`, in a string.

And why would you want a tab that links back to the member being viewed? You're already viewing that member.

This will provide the url of the displayed member: `bp_displayed_user_domain()`

So you could do this:

```
function redirect_user_to_tab3(){
    bp_core_redirect( bp_displayed_user_domain() );
}
```

If you just want the user name for the currently displayed user so that you can build an url, you could do this:

```
function redirect_user_to_tab3(){
    $url = site_url() . '/slug/' . bp_get_displayed_user_username();
    bp_core_redirect( $url );
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but you didn't understand me ,,, i fixed the first part of my probleme by declaring my var `$user = wp_get_current_user();` inside the function `function redirect_user_to_tab3()` and this worked fine for my profile ,,,, the tab i create doesn't link to the member viewed wich has the slug of members ,,, my tab has a different slug then the username of the profile being viewed (user2) so i want the final url like this `http://localhost/wordpress2/slug/user2` ,,, i know i should call something different than ` wp_get_current_user()` to find infos about the profile viewed ,,

Comment: See my edited answer above.

Comment: thats it ,,, it worked just like i want ,,,,,, you're a master ,,,, it's been 2 weeks i'm trying to find the solution ,,,, i cant thank you enough ,,,,